# Como Adicionar DLL no Visual Studio? (Forma não convencional)

Tags: visual-studio, dll, importação

Estou tentando adicionar algumas `DLL's` ao meu projeto no Visual Studio (De forma não convencional).

O que quero dizer é: Dentro do meu projeto, porém fora das ***References*** !

**Conforme a imagem que segue:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A razão de usar as DLLs dessa forma, é porque o Visual Studio não permite inserir algumas `DLLs` em **References**.

Sei que existe essa forma de inserir as DLLs, como mostrado na imagem, porém, não sei como fazer esse tipo de importação.

- Como importar DLLs dessa forma?

Comment: Porque ele não permite inserir essas dll's?

Comment: A mensagem que o VS da é essa: **could not be added.  Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.**  São 8 DLLs, porém, O VS só permite importar 2. Eu teria que fazer importação conforme a imagem(Dessa forma sei que da certo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que vi, o que você está tentando fazer de fato, é apenas incluir um arquivo no seu projeto.

1. Você deve abrir a pasta do seu projeto, por dentro do visual studio mesmo. Com o botão direito, clique sobre seu projeto e depois vá na opção "Open folder in file explorer":
   [image: Abrir pasta do seu projeto]
2. Inclua sua `.dll` ou arquivo desejado dentro da pasta que se abriu.
3. Volte ao `visual studio` e clique no botão "Show all files" dentro da janela `Solution Explorer`:

[image: Botão show all files]

4. Note que seu arquivo irá aparecer meio apagado, clique com o botão direito sobre ele e clique na opção "Include in project".

[image: Botão Include in projeto]

5. Pronto, depois disso sua `.dll` já estará dentro do seu projeto...

Você pode ainda configura-la para ser copiada para o `output` do seu projeto, clicando sobre ela com o botão direito, e selecionado a opção `Properties`. Dentro da janela `File properties`, configure a opção `Copy to output directory`.

[image: Configuração do arquivo]

Só uma dica, o `visual studio 2019` já faz os passos 3 e 4 automaticamente para você... Acho que só nas versões mais antigas isso ainda é necessário.

Espero ter ajudado.